# WWW:Facebook:Api Auth Token

Tags: perl, cpan

-----------------------------here received 32 length key auth_token 
        Error during REST auth.getSession call:
        params = 
             api_key:--------------
             auth_token:-------------------------------
             call_id:------------.-----[like a decimal values
             format:JSON
              method:facebook.auth.getSession
              v:1.0
       response =
       {"error_code":100,"error_msg":"Invalid parameter","request_args":[

```
   {"key":"api_key","value":"---------------"},
   {"key":"auth_token","value":"----------------------"},
   {"key":"call_id","value":"-------------------"},
   {"key":"format","value":"JSON"},
   {"key":"method","value":"facebook.auth.getSession"},
   {"key":"v","value":"1.0"},
   {"key":"sig","value":"f253b75e337776756a1fba88f085c269"}]}
    WWW::Facebook::API=HASH(0xa203ce8)
```

i need to convert the received auth_token how to do that ? How can i validate that Received one correct key or not.

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl -w

 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use CGI;
 use WWW::Facebook::API;
 use WWW::Facebook::API::Auth;

 use HTTP::Request;
 use LWP;

 my $TMP    = $ENV{HOME}.'/tmp';

 my $facebook_api      = '--------';
 my $facebook_secret   = '-------';
 my $facebook_clientid = '--------';

 my $gmail_user        = '-------';
 my $gmail_password    = '--------';

 my $client = WWW::Facebook::API->new(

 desktop         => 1,
 api_version     => '1.0',
 api_key         => $facebook_api,
 secret          => $facebook_secret,
 throw_errors    => 1,     
 );

 $client->app_id($facebook_clientid);

 local $SIG{INT} = sub {
 print "Logging out of Facebookn";
 my $r = $client->auth->logout;
 exit(1);
  };

 my $token = $client->auth->create_token;
 print "$token \n";

 $client->auth->get_session($token);
 print "$client \n";
```

Answer (score 0):

WWW:Facebook:Api is deprecated (last version - 12 Mar 2010). It seems API is broken. You should use Facebook::Graph instead.